# Python run the same function several times with various arguments in realtime without knowing how many instances are required

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

```html
import time
import threading
import ctypes

def fun1(txt):
  return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, txt, "title", 0)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=fun1, args=("1"))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=fun1, args=("2"))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=fun1, args=("3"))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
```

I have this code which works great but I don't want it to be limited to only three instances, when called, I'd like something that can handle any number of instances operating in real-time.

any guidance appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a container... loop over the container? The same way you handle an arbitrary number of objects always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
import threading
import ctypes

def func(*args, **kwArg):
    func2(f)

def func2(f):
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, f, "Title", 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []

    fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
    for f in fruits:
        t = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(f))  
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```